# Send Email onclick of button in Salescloud Automatically through SFMC

Tags: triggered-send, marketing-cloud-connect

I have a requirement where i need to send an email through onclick of "SendEmail" button in Account object.Where Emails are from SFMC email templates. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Hello. Could you tell more details? Is this custom fuctionality?

Comment: Yes I had created a custom button Send email  in Account onclick of the button i should send email for the contact related account with SFMC template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swetha, The first pre-requisite for making this possible is a fully configured Marketing Cloud Connector setup. If you have done that, then I have a simpler solution than setting up a new button.

You are allowed to send individual emails directly from Sales Cloud using the Integration, you can refer to the [Individual sends documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_send_single_email.htm&type=5) for more details. If you're unable to find this option, you might need to edit the page layout and add the relevant section on Accounts.

Let me know if this helps.